# EXCEL Error when opening up XLSXWRITER from PANDAS

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have a similar problem with PANDAS and XLSXWRITER that was asked earlier:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61354546/error-opening-excel-xlsx-files-from-pandas-xlsxwriter
```

When I open the Excel WORKBOOK generated by XLSXWriter I get an error everytime:

```
We found a problem with some content in....
```

This is the contents of the XML Error Message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
-<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
<logFileName>error046800_01.xml</logFileName>
<summary>Errors were detected in file 'Z:\python\data\20201219.xlsx'</summary>
-<repairedRecords>
<repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part</repairedRecord>
<repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml part</repairedRecord>
<repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet3.xml part</repairedRecord>
<repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet4.xml part</repairedRecord>
<repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet5.xml part</repairedRecord>
<repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet6.xml part</repairedRecord>
<repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet7.xml part</repairedRecord>
<repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet8.xml part</repairedRecord>
<repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet9.xml part</repairedRecord>
<repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet10.xml part</repairedRecord>
<repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet11.xml part</repairedRecord>
<repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet12.xml part</repairedRecord>
<repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet13.xml part</repairedRecord>
<repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet14.xml part</repairedRecord>
<repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Cell i</repairedRecord>
<repairedRecord>Repaired Records: C</repairedRecord>
<repairedRecord xml:space="preserve">Repaired Records: </repairedRecord>
</repairedRecords>
</recoveryLog>
```

I tried the suggestion from the above link but I still get the errors:

```
WORKBOOK = xlsxwriter.Workbook(WORKBOOK_NAME, {'strings_to_formulas': False})
```

The WORKBOOK seems to recover most of the data but ALL formatting of Cells is lost.

Any suggestions would be most welcome

---

Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: Please share the excel or a part of the excel you are trying to open.

Comment: I assume you want the xlsx file that was generated by xlsxwriter

I created a test xlsx file but I can not figure out how attach the xlsx file to this ticket

Guidance on how to share the file?

Thx

Comment: link added to test file that demonstrates the errors

Comment: does anyone have any idea on how to Troubleshoot and resolve this issue?