# Which arguments is 'FutureWarning: Use of **kwargs is deprecated, use engine_kwargs instead' refering to?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I got the following waring from that code:

```
    file = r'.\changed_activities.xlsx'
    with pd.ExcelWriter(file,
                        engine='openpyxl',
                        mode='a',
                        if_sheet_exists='new') as writer:
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=activity[0:30])


FutureWarning: Use of **kwargs is deprecated, use engine_kwargs instead. with pd.ExcelWriter(file,
```

What I can't seem to read from the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html#pandas.ExcelWriter) is which of my arguments I need to replace?
the examples are e.g. this, but I don't see how that translates to my code.

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(
    "path_to_file.xlsx",
    engine="openpyxl",
    mode="a",
    engine_kwargs={"keep_vba": True}
) as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet2")
```

And maybe in a more open question: how/where can I understand something like that that in a general case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use

```
pd.ExcelWriter('out.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', engine_kwargs={'options':{'strings_to_urls': False}})
```

Instead of

```
pd.ExcelWriter('out.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', options={'strings_to_urls': False}})
```

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately there is no way to deduce this from the documentation (at least not in the way they are currently worded) since it doesn't explain what triggers the warning.

If we look at the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/06d230151e6f18fdb8139d09abf539867a8cd481/pandas/io/excel/_base.py#L968) of `pd.ExcelWriter`:

```py
def __new__(
        cls,
        path: FilePath | WriteExcelBuffer | ExcelWriter,
        engine: str | None = None,
        date_format: str | None = None,
        datetime_format: str | None = None,
        mode: str = "w",
        storage_options: StorageOptions = None,
        if_sheet_exists: Literal["error", "new", "replace", "overlay"] | None = None,
        engine_kwargs: dict | None = None,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        if kwargs:
            if engine_kwargs is not None:
                raise ValueError("Cannot use both engine_kwargs and **kwargs")
            warnings.warn(
                "Use of **kwargs is deprecated, use engine_kwargs instead.",
                FutureWarning,
                stacklevel=find_stack_level(),
            )
```

Any keyword argument that is passed to `pd.ExcelWriter` which is **not** specified as an argument of `__new__` will trigger the `if kwargs` condition.

In your case, you should move the `sheet_name` argument to the `engine_kwargs` dict.